# Metafunction to detect template class inheriting through CRTP

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have an interface that is like this:

```
template<typename Concrete, typename T>
class Interface{
    ...
}
```

and concrete implementations of it:

```
template<typename T>
class Concrete : public Interface<Concrete<T>, T>
{
    ...
    using type = typename T;
}
```

I would like to have a metafunction that could check whether a certain type comes from `Interface`.

As an example, let's say the interface only had one template argument (and hence it wouldn't produce children template classes):

```
template<typename Concrete>
class A
{
    ...
}

class B : public A<B>
{
    ...
}
```

in this case, I could use:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_A
{
    static bool const value = std::is_base<A<T>, T>::value;
}
```

My question is what is the best approach to produce a similar metafunction for the case where there is an additional template argument. It should look like:

```
template<typename T>    
struct is_Interface{}
```

To be clear, I could produce

```
 template<template <class> class T>    
 struct is_Interface
 {
  using dummy_type = void;
  static bool const value = std::is_base<Interface<T<dummy_type>, dummy_type>, T<dummy_type>>::value;
 }
```

but I would like something where I pass the concrete type and not the template class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of overload resolution:

```
template <template <class> class Concrete, class T>
std::true_type is_Interface_impl(Interface<Concrete<T>, T> *);

std::false_type is_Interface_impl(...);

template<typename T>
struct is_Interface : decltype(is_Interface_impl(std::declval<T*>())) { };
```

Derived-to-base pointer conversions are allowed in template argument deduction, that's how the first overload of `is_Interface_impl` can detect and match the relationship. If the conversion cannot happen, SFINAE applies and overload resolution falls back onto the vararg function.

[See it live on Coliru!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ae9a7f6627b4b4a)